# How to using Convolutional Neural Network whitout data augmentation

Tags: tensorflow2.0, conv-neural-network

i want to ask. A few days ago i learn convolutional neural network or CNN using a data augmentation, and i want to try if not using it, but there's a identation problem which made me confused. Can someone help me to fix it ? [The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b440L.png)

And this is the result when i used data augmentation
[The result using data augmentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOniS.png)

Answer (score 0):

it's an indentation error as it was reported, can you c/c this code and replace yours with this one to try if it works ?

```
train_generator = train_data_path, target_size = (img_rows,img_cols), batch_size=batch_size,class_mode='categorical'
validation_generator = validation_data_path, target_size=(img_rows,img_cols),batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=False,class_mode='categorical'
```

Edit : Sorry i didn't answer your question, if you want to use CNN without data augmentation, following your way ( images you've provided ) you'll have to change one line of code :

```
 train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale =1. / 255)
```